# In Python, how do I comment out a specific part of the code only?

Tags: python, syntax

```
plt.plot (X, Y, label='xyz1', linewidth=2, linestyle='--', color='red', marker='v')
```

I don't want to delete `linewidth=2,` but only comment out that portion, in case I want it for future use. How do I do it?

I tried something like this but it didn't work:

```
plt.plot (X, Y, label='xyz1', #linewidth=2,\# linestyle='--', color='red', marker='v')
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I don't think Python supports in-code-line commenting.

Comment: Thanks. If you had to do it, how would you do it?

Comment: Put the function parameters on seperate lines, and comment out one, I suppose...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split out the arguments on separate lines so you can comment them out individually.

```
plt.plot (
    X, Y,
    label='xyz1',
    # linewidth=2,
    linestyle='--',
    color='red',
    marker='v')
```

Comment: Yep, this is exactly what I had in mind.